# Show that the following integral is zero.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals

This problem is very challenging. The integral cannot be be solved in terms of elementary functions.

Show the following integral vanishes:
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \int_{-3}^{-1} \frac{1}{e^{0.5x+e^{2-x}}+e^{0.5x}}f(x)dx+\displaystyle \int_{1}^{3} \frac{1}{e^{0.5x+e^{2-x}}+e^{0.5x}}f(x) dx
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\displaystyle \int_{-3}^{-1} e^{\frac{1}{t^2+4t+3}}\cos{2\pi x t} dt+ \displaystyle \int_{1}^{3} e^{\frac{1}{t^2-4t+3}}\cos{2\pi x t} dt
\end{equation}

Perhaps, one of the ways would be to find the series of $f(x)$ and plug in the given integral, but I still find challenges there?

Comment: Have you checked this numerically?

Comment: YES, The answer is close to zero, in Sage and in Mathematica. We can't reduce the error much. I also have a long proof that this is true, but that is not the direct substitution.

Comment: Can't you simplify $f(x)$ a bit with the substitution $u=-t$? Not sure that is going to help you in the long run, but it should just be twice one of the two integrals.

Comment: Also, if you have a proof that this is true, what precisely are you asking for?

Comment: @DanielOfJack The proof I have is indirect in the sense that it uses many theorems, implying the integral  vanishes for this $f(x)$.

Comment: @ersh But you then known what you need to know; why are you looking for a "simpler" or more "direct" proof at all?

Comment: @DanielOfJack I just want to make sure my proof is correct. Also, it is natural to verify things by direct substitution whenever possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87395/discussion-between-danielofjack-and-ersh).

Comment: Will this help: $$\int_{-c}\vec F\cdot \vec Tds=-\int_c\vec F\cdot \vec Tds$$?